# AVAudioPlayer no sound when device is muted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

How is the easiest way to program the AVAudioPlayer in the way that it is not playing music, while the device is muted(the physical slider on the left hand side is switched towards back of the phone)? It should just play music, if the device is unmuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a slider that controls the volume for your AVAudioplayer, and an outlet for the slider that gets the value of the slider. When the slider value is set to zero that means when the volume is zero just use "youplayername.pause()" to pause the audio and when the volume is not zero, you can have two cases i.e. the audio is playing or the audio is paused. so you can set a boolean for condition of audio playing and code it accordingly. Use nested if else to achieve this result. I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: I also thought about that but for example if you play a game from the App Store for example Mega Jump or something in this lines, the sound is just playing while the iPhone is unmuted (the physical slider on the left hand side is switched towards the display). Do you know how to put that into code?

Comment: Hello, I don't know how to code it but what I know is you can do it by using AVAudioSession. I don't really have a fair idea on how to do it. But you can have a look at these links and get it done https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession   Check the following website out for an example: http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/11/18/taking-control-of-the-volume-buttons-on-ios-like-camera/ (The code is old so one might take a while to understand)

Comment: But basically you will have to Initialize an Audio session then activate it and then get the changes by using AddPropertyListener. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look in this.